# replace a particular text in all the files using single line shell command

Tags: shell, sed, shellexecute

I have a renamed js file which I have to call in each of my php pages. Now I want to replace that old name with the new one using shell.
what iam using is this:

```
sed -i ’s/old/new/g’ *
```

but this is giving the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command:
```

How can I do this replacement?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are probably less verbose solutions, but here we go:

```
for i in *; do sed -i 's/old/new/g' "$i"; done
```

Mind you, it will only work on the current level of the file system, files in subdirectories will not be modified. Also, you might want to replace * with *.php, or make backups (pass an argument after -i, and it will make a backup with the given extension).

Comment: on OSX you have BSD sed, and need to pass a file extension for backups to the -i option.  Check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-with-i-option-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux)

Comment: I get `sed: couldn't edit includes: not a regular file` for many folders.

Comment: I assume they are FIFOs or device files, or something other than a regular file. If you have non-regular files, you will have to use something else instead of a glob (like find -type f ...).

Answer (score 56):

```
sed -i.bak 's/old/new/g' *.php
```

to do it recursively

```
find /path -type f -iname '*.php' -exec sed -i.bak 's/old/new/' "{}" +;
```

Comment: @WimPruiksma, I get the same error from BSD sed on the mac, but not from GNU sed (installed as gsed with brew).

Comment: sed -i is not POSIX standard required, so it's not in OS X or BSD  iirc.

Comment: FTR: I've just replaced in place with sed and FreeBSD 11.3 using `sed -i '' -e '...'`, as described in answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place

Answer (score 12):

this one is very simple, without for or loop, and takes care of any number or nested directories

`grep -rl 'oldText' [folderName-optional] | xargs sed -i 's/oldText/newText/g'`

Comment: I get `No such file or directory` with this one and recursive directories.

Comment: @dman probably you have executed it with   [folderName-optional] without changing it .  you may remove it, or can keep only single dot without quotes  `grep -rl 'oldText' . | xargs sed -i 's/oldText/newText/g' `

Answer (score 10):

You are using Unicode apostrophes (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK - U2019) instead of ASCII (0x27) apostrophes around your `sed` command argument.

Answer (score 9):

I know I'm really late but still:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php"|xargs sed -i 's/old/new/g'
```

Comment: Best answer here.

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -pi -e 's/old/new/g' *.php
```

Comment: got an error on OSX `zsh: argument list too long: perl`

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, providing the OSX compatible version of the above accepted answer (to answer comment from @jamescampbell)

```
for i in *.php; do sed -i .orig 's/old/new/g' "$i"; done
```

This command creates `.orig` backup files.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
ls | grep "php" > files.txt
for file in $(cat files.txt); do
    sed 's/catch/send/g' $file > TMPfile.php && mv TMPfile.php $file
done
```

Comment: Don't know about useless - but its a very ugly approach, then there's the fact that using fixed temporary file name (files.txt, TMPfile.php) will break if there's any concurrency.