# sed command with -i option failing on Mac, but works on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, bash, sed

I've successfully used the following `sed` command to search/replace text in Linux:

```
sed -i 's/old_link/new_link/g' *
```

However, when I try it on my Mac OS X, I get:

> "command c expects \ followed by text"

I thought my Mac runs a normal BASH shell.  What's up?

**EDIT:**

According to @High Performance, this is due to Mac `sed` being of a different (BSD) flavor, so my question would therefore be how do I replicate this command in BSD `sed`?

**EDIT:**

Here is an actual example that causes this:

```
sed -i 's/hello/gbye/g' *
```

Comment: This means that `sed` sees a "c" in your data as a command. Are you using a variable? Please post something that more closely represents the actual command and some data that you're processing. You can get a simple demonstration of this error by doing `echo x | sed c`.

Comment: @Dennis, the simple command above causes this, though the data it's processing is an entire website (I'm converting all image links), including html and css files...

Answer (score 577, accepted):

The `-i` option (alternatively, `--in-place`) means that you want files edited in-place, rather than streaming the change to a new place.

Modifying a file in-place suggests a need for a backup file - and so a user-specified extension is expected after `-i`, but the parsing of the extension argument is handled differently under GNU sed & Mac (BSD) sed:

- [**GNU**](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#Command_002dLine-Options:%7E:text=If%20no%20extension%20is%20supplied%2C%20the%20original%20file%20is%20overwritten%20without%20making%20a%20backup.) : "If no extension is supplied, the original file is overwritten without making a backup." - effectively, you can omit specify a file extension altogether. The extension must be supplied *immediately* after the `-i`, with no intervening space.
- [**Mac (BSD)**](https://man.openbsd.org/sed.1#:%7E:text=If%20a%20zero%20length%20extension,ranges%20are%20reset%20between%20files.) : "If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved." - you *must* supply an extension, but it can be the empty string '' if you want, to disable the backup.

So GNU & Mac will interpret this differently:

```
sed -i 's/hello/bye/g' jkl.txt
```

- **GNU** : No extension is supplied immediately after the `-i`, so create no backup, use `s/hello/bye/g` as the text-editing command, and act on the file `jkl.txt` in-place.
- **Mac (BSD)** : Use `s/hello/bye/g` is the backup file extension (!), use  `jkl.txt` as the text-editing command, but uh-oh!: the command code given there is `j` (not, eg `s`, a valid command code for substitution), so error with `invalid command code j`.

#### Portable solution

To get a portable command, you can use this invocation, that works across both GNU `sed` *and* Mac (BSD) `sed` in Mac OS X Mavericks (v10.9, released June 2013) and above:

```
sed -i'' -e 's/hello/bye/g' jkl.txt
```

Placing the extension immediately after the `-i` (eg `-i''` or `-i'.bak'`, without a space) is what GNU `sed` expects, and is now accepted by Mac (BSD) `sed` too, though it wasn't tolerated by earlier versions (eg with Mac OS X v10.6, a space was *required* after `-i`, eg `-i '.bak'`).

The `-e` parameter allows us to be explicit about where we're declaring the edit command.

Until Mac OS was updated in 2013, there wasn't any portable command across GNU and Mac (BSD), as these variants also failed:

- `sed -i -e ...` - does not work on OS X as it creates `-e` backups
- `sed -i '' -e ...` - fails on GNU

When there wasn't a `sed` command working on all platforms, you could have tried using another command to achieve the same result, e.g. `perl -i -pe's/old_link/new_link/g' *`.

Comment: I had the same issue. Thanks for this solution. But where I tried with 'man sed' to find the description of '-i', nothing about using -i '' to ignore backups is there. This is my first blame. Second, when the error "command expects \ followed by text" shows up, why doesn't it directly tell us that it expects a backup name for the option '-i'!!?? Such thing happens everywhere: you get an error but not why the error, then you search for the manual which explains nothing about it. Then you google it to find someone else also has the same problem. I mean, why not giving example in the manual?

Comment: or tell us why the error is there instead of only a information-less message that an error happens. This is a suggestion to all tool makers, if they can ever read this comment.

Comment: @lukmac As far as `sed` can tell, you DID supply a backup suffix. The backup suffix is `s/old_link/new_link/g`. The next argument after that is supposed to be the editing commands. Because it interpreted the commands as the backup name, it then took the first filename as the editing commands, but they weren't valid.

Comment: Will this always be an issue?  Is there some way that Apple might be able to create a workaround / package GNU sed with OSX?  Or, couldn't GNU sed support `sed -i '' -e ...`?

Comment: `sed -i'' -e` seems to not work as expected on mac 10.14

Comment: Oh, the `perl` this is so ugly, but so nice. Thanks for a way out of this mess!

Comment: `sed -i -- ...` seems to work fine. Also mentioned @https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245014/619961

Comment: You can often avoid -i altogether by directing stdout to the new file. `sed -e 's/old_link/new_link/g' filename > filename.old`.
But you'd need to loop over the filenames if you wanted to apply it to multiple files.

Comment: ` perl -i -pe's/old_link/new_link/g' *` does the trick!

Answer (score 93):

I believe on OS X when you use -i an extension for the backup files is *required*. Try:

```
sed -i .bak 's/hello/gbye/g' *
```

Using GNU `sed` the extension is *optional*.

Answer (score 84):

This works with both GNU and BSD versions of sed:

```
sed -i'' -e 's/old_link/new_link/g' *
```

or with backup:

```
sed -i'.bak' -e 's/old_link/new_link/g' *
```

Note missing space after `-i` option! (Necessary for GNU sed)

Comment: The first one doesn't work on OSX (I've just tested it on 10.6.8)

Comment: For me on OS X (10.10.3), the first one created backup files suffixed with -e. No good. The second one was the only thing that worked for me consistently between Ubuntu and OS X. I didn't want backup files though, so I had to run a `rm` command right after to delete it.

Comment: First line should be rewritten with a space to work on 10.10:

`sed -i'' ...` => `sed -i '' ...`

Comment: @DanielJomphe But adding this space don't work on GNU sed

Comment: @marcin first one works for me as well on OSX 10.11.2. Only thing is that it creates a backup file, which needs to be removed afterwards. Second looks better, as we don't have to figure out the filename later on.

Comment: and then clean up the annoying .bak files with `find . -name '*.bak' | xargs rm`

Comment: downvoted since I wasted so much time on this and it didn't work. (the first thing). The backup works but I wanted without, and `perl -i -pe` from the other answer gave that :)

Comment: Didn't work on macOS 12

Comment: It does work on macOS 12, but it is important to also use `-e` before the editing command (without the string after `-i`, `-e` is optional).

Comment: -i and -i'' are exactly the same, (as is '-i', "-i", -i'''''''' and so on), so having those ''s at the end makes no difference...

Comment: @DanielJomphe i can confirm this (mac 14.0). Otherwise a backup file was created in my case.

Answer (score 84):

Had the same problem in Mac and solved it with `brew`:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

and use as

```
gsed SED_COMMAND
```

you can set as well set `sed` as alias to `gsed` (if you want):

```
alias sed=gsed
```

Comment: Why did you give exactly the [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-with-i-option-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux/10304970#10304970) as [Ohad Kravchick](http://stackoverflow.com/users/455262/ohad-kravchick)?

Comment: setting alias like this is not a great idea

Comment: Instead of an alias, as recommended in the corresponding brew page, add it to path: PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"

Comment: Since we're all lazy developers here, add this line to your `~/.zshrc` or bashrc file:

`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

And then run `source ~/.zshrc`

Change to your rc file of choice! Then run `which sed` to check if it's been changed.

Answer (score 33):

Or, you can install the GNU version of sed in your Mac, called gsed, and use it using the standard Linux syntax.

For that, install `gsed` using ports (if you don't have it, get it at http://www.macports.org/) by running `sudo port install gsed`. Then, you can run `sed -i 's/old_link/new_link/g' *`

Comment: .. or if you use homebrew, then install `gnu-sed`

Comment: Thanks @sudar. This works for me: `gsed -i "s/$FND/$RPL/g" "$file"`

Answer (score 11):

Your Mac does indeed run a BASH shell, but this is more a question of which implementation of sed you are dealing with.  On a Mac sed comes from BSD and is subtly different from the sed you might find on a typical Linux box.  I suggest you `man sed`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the BSD issue- But I'm quite sed illiterate and just need a quick fix for my command- quick glance at man isn't telling me anything

Comment: Most SO answers are buried somewhere in a man, but that's what SO is for- busy people who need answers from smart people

Answer (score 11):

Sinetris' answer is right, but I use this with `find` command to be more specific about what files I want to change. In general this should work (tested on osx `/bin/bash`):

```
find . -name "*.smth" -exec sed -i '' 's/text1/text2/g' {} \;
```

In general when using `sed` without `find` in complex projects is less efficient.

Comment: `-exec` is very nice! I'm just wondering if the slash in the end is actually need

Comment: @YeLiu: without the ``\`` , the `;` got interpreted by the shell when I tried such

Answer (score 11):

Insead of calling sed with `sed`, I do `./bin/sed`

And this is the wrapper script in my `~/project/bin/sed`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
  exec "gsed" "$@"
else
  exec "sed" "$@"
fi
```

Don't forget to `chmod 755` the wrapper script.

Comment: assumes you've done `brew install gnu-sed` beforehand on your Mac

Answer (score 8):

I've created a function to handle `sed` difference between MacOS (tested on MacOS 10.12) and other OS:

```
OS=`uname`
# $(replace_in_file pattern file)
function replace_in_file() {
    if [ "$OS" = 'Darwin' ]; then
        # for MacOS
        sed -i '' -e "$1" "$2"
    else
        # for Linux and Windows
        sed -i'' -e "$1" "$2"
    fi
}
```

Usage:

```
$(replace_in_file 's,MASTER_HOST.*,MASTER_HOST='"$MASTER_IP"',' "./mysql/.env")
```

Where:

`,` is a delimeter

`'s,MASTER_HOST.*,MASTER_HOST='"$MASTER_IP"','` is pattern

`"./mysql/.env"` is path to file

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option in bash scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash

GO_OS=${GO_OS:-"linux"}

function detect_os {
    # Detect the OS name
    case "$(uname -s)" in
      Darwin)
        host_os=darwin
        ;;
      Linux)
        host_os=linux
        ;;
      *)
        echo "Unsupported host OS. Must be Linux or Mac OS X." >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac

   GO_OS="${host_os}"
}

detect_os

if [ "${GO_OS}" == "darwin" ]; then
    sed -i '' -e ...
else
    sed -i -e ...
fi
```

Comment: can you somehow only  condition the `gsed` presence and use that as a varaible??

Comment: @perrohunter A little bit late (only 1 year and an half ), but yes it's possible. E.g.
`if type gsed &> /dev/null; then; echo "use gsed"; else; echo "use sed"; fi;`

Comment: @Sinetris better late than never hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers indicate, there is not a way to use sed portably across OS X and Linux without making backup files. So, I instead used this Ruby one-liner to do so:

```
ruby -pi -e "sub(/ $/, '')" ./config/locales/*.yml
```

In my case, I needed to call it from a `rake` task (i.e., inside a Ruby script), so I used this additional level of quoting:

```
sh %q{ruby -pi -e "sub(/ $/, '')" ./config/locales/*.yml}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to apply environment variables to template file (no backup need).

#### 1. Create template with {{FOO}} for later replace.

```
echo "Hello {{FOO}}" > foo.conf.tmpl
```

#### 2. Replace {{FOO}} with FOO variable and output to new foo.conf file

```
FOO="world" && sed -e "s/{{FOO}}/$FOO/g" foo.conf.tmpl > foo.conf
```

Working both **macOS 10.12.4** and **Ubuntu 14.04.5**

Answer (score -3):

```
sed -ie 's/old_link/new_link/g' *
```

Works on both BSD & Linux with gnu sed

Comment: This creates on linux another filename with `e` appended

Comment: Broken, better to remove it.

Comment: It is working on Mac and Linux. What is the issue with this solution?

Comment: No, it does not work on Mac BSD Sed - it would create a backupfile with 'e' added to the filename.