# sed code to match http://www.domain.com/ and replace with just a / in all files in a directory

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I've been searching for this answer for three hours now and I still can't get anything to work.  When I run things like this:

```
 sed -i 's/http\:\/\/www\.domain\.org\//\//g checkout_*.php
```

It drops me into another command line (sorry, I'm very new to sed).

I just want to cd to a dir, grep the dir to see if the string is there then run a replace so I can change my paths from absolute to relative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to close your `'`. You can also make your command cleaner by using a different sed delimiter to `/` so that you don't have to escape all those forward slashes in your URL. For example, you can use `!`, as shown below:

```
sed -i 's!http://www\.domain\.org/!/!g' checkout_*.php
```

Comment: The sed command is slightly different for mac. You need to specify a backup extension immediately following the -i paramaeter, eg. '.original' as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4247319/4158458

Answer (score 3):

You just appear to be missing the closing `'`

```
sed -i 's/http\:\/\/www\.domain\.org\//\//g' checkout_*.php
```

Should do what you want ok. But I'd warn you against doing the `-i` switch without first doing a dry run.

Comment: Yeah, you both were right.  Sorry I didn't catch it before posting.  thanks very much!