# Getting sed error

Tags: shell, sed

I'm new to shell scripting but getting this error and cant figure out what up.

```
sed: 1: "/Users/local/Do ...": extra characters at the end of d command
sed: 1: "/Users/local/Do ...": extra characters at the end of d command
sed: 1: "/Users/local/Do ...": extra characters at the end of d command
sed: 1: "/Users/local/Do ...": extra characters at the end of d command
```

Here is the script I'm running

```
for fl in $(S_convertPath ${RESOURCE_DIR}/db)/db.changelog-*xml; do
    sed -i "s/HOSTNAME/${IP_ADDRESS}/g" $fl
done
```

Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Given that `sed` seems to think you're running a `delete line` command (`d`), you may want to output the command to see what's actually *in* that environment variable of yours:

```
for fl in $(S_convertPath ${RESOURCE_DIR}/db)/db.changelog-*xml; do
    echo sed -i "s/HOSTNAME/${PSM_SERVER_ADDRESS}/g" $fl
done
```

There's a good chance the `PSM_SERVER_ADDRESS` is corrupting your `sed` command (and may need to be processed to make it clean). One way to do this (provided you have a recent enough `sed`) would be to use delimiters that do not appear in the environment variable, for example:

```
sed -i "s?HOSTNAME?${PSM_SERVER_ADDRESS}?g" $fl
```

---

Since you've accepted this answer, I may as well add the resolution for the additional problem you found. It appears that BSD `sed`, unlike Linux, has a *requirement* that you provide an extension to the `-i` option. So, while Linux allows:

```
sed -i "sed-command"
```

to edit in-place, the BSD variant needs to have:

```
sed -i "" "sed-command"
```

with an empty backup suffix.

Without that, `sed` may use your command as the extension and your first file name as the command.

Comment: It is.  The value `PSM_SERVER_ADDRESS` is a path (which contains `/` characters) so the s command interprets those `/` characters as its delimiters (e.g., `s/HOSTNAME//Users/davidkavanagh/path/g`.  Looks like alternate delimiters should be used.  Perhaps `s@HOSTNAME@${PSM_SERVER_ADDRESS}/g`.

Comment: IP_ADDRESS is equal to a function that gets ip using hostname -i for use across all platforms

Comment: @daverocks, you _still_ need to run the modified script I provided to get the line echoed, even with the changes you have made. It's the only way to know what the commands being given to `sed` are.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yep, I had recently encountered such issue in one of my sed script. Changing the delimiter works. Sed gets confused when it passes the variable value to the substitution field that happens to look like '/'. My preference is an underscore '_' but you can use '?' too.

Comment: Sorry, ran debugging with echo and it printed what was expecting it got IP address and listed the 4 files paths to change. 'sed -i s/HOSTNAME/12.27.2.12 /g /Users/davidkava/Docu.....og-1.0.xml' I tried delimiter ? and @ with no joy so going to research more thanks for help

Comment: found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux had to use single quotes after -i, thanks for help