# Performing a sed -i on a list of files in stdin

Tags: bash, sed, django-urls, ack, django-1.5

So I recently upgraded Django from 1.4 to 1.5. I found out I need to update all my template codes to add single quotes like from

```
{% url user_detail pk=user.pk %}
```

to

```
{% url 'user_detail' pk=user.pk %}
```

I'm kind of new to bash commands like `sed`, but I approached my issue in 2 parts.

The 1st part was to get a list of all the files that needs updating. I did that with

```
ack "{% url" | cut -d ":" -f1 | uniq
```

this will give me an ouput like

```
templates/some_file.html
templates/admin/another_file.html
```

The 2nd part was playing around with sed

```
cat templates/some_file.html | sed "s/{% url \([A-Za-z0-9_]*\) /{% url '\1' /g"
```

Both of those commands work fine. Now the question is

**how do I combine those two commands so that `sed` will add single-quotes around the url name in every file found by `ack`?**

If I try

```
ack "{% url" | cut -d ":" -f1 | uniq | sed -i "s/{% url \([A-Za-z0-9_]*\) /{% url '\1' /g"
```

it gives me the error

```
sed: -i may not be used with stdin
```

**EDIT**

I'm running OS X (BSD variant) so I needed to use `sed -i "" "s/{% url \([A-Za-z0-9_]*\) /{% url '\1' /g"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ack -l "{% url" | xargs sed -i "s/{% url \([A-Za-z0-9_]*\) /{% url '\1' /g"
```

`-l` lists matching files from `ack` (a simpler version of your `cut`/`uniq`).  `xargs` performs the operation on each argument acquired from the pipe (i.e. each file).  What you were trying to do would be `sed` on the actual string of the list of files from stdin which of course can't be updated in place.

Comment: I ran that command and when I did `ack` again I noticed that none of the files changed. Well I did get one error: `sed: 1: "doors/templatetags/brea ...": extra characters at the end of d command` but I think that's just my `sed` expression not catching all the cases.

Comment: @hobbes3 it's weird that none of the files changed -- I did a very minimal test.  Try `sed` without `-i` first to see if you get any output

Comment: ok I ran `ack -l "{% url" | xargs sed "s/{% url \([A-Za-z0-9_.]*\) /{% url '\1' /g" | grep '{% url'` (I forgot to find `.` inside the regex) and it shows the output wth the added single-quote.

Comment: Is it because that one error `sed: 1: ... extra characters at the end of the d command` is aborting the whole `sed` rewrite of the files?

Comment: This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648328/getting-sed-error) helped. I changed the command to `sed -i "" "s/{% url ...` and it worked! I failed to mention my system is OS X, which is a BSD variant. Thanks.

Comment: @hobbes3 ah, I see.  I'm on a Linux machine