# delete lines awk

Tags: awk

A very simple question (I think)

I´m learning to edit files with `awk`

I want to search all the liner from a file and delete all the lines with the word acetate

I have tried

```
awk 'match($0,"acetate") == 0 {print $0}' filename.txt > filename.txt
```

However this returns a empty txt file.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -pi -e 'if(/acetate/){undef $_}' your_file
```

This will do an in-place replacement, which means your lines in the file with the string 'acetate' will be deleted automatically. Or you can also do:

```
perl -pi -e 'undef $_ if /acetate/' your_file
```

or

```
sed -i.bak '/acetate/d' temp
```

Comment: The question was about awk not perl.

Answer (score 12):

Try doing this :

```
awk '!/acetate/{print}' filename.txt > new_filename.txt &&
mv new_filename.txt filename.txt
```

or simply :

```
awk '!/acetate/' filename.txt > new_filename.txt &&
mv new_filename.txt filename.txt
```

You can't print and modify a file in the same time with `awk`. If you want' to do it in the same command, try using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
sed -i '/acetate/d' filename.txt
```

or for Mac Os X :

```
sed -i.'' '/acetate/d' filename.txt
```

Comment: thanks sputnick, sed might be the solution. However, I´m getting the following message: extra characters at the end of N command. any suggestion?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux

Comment: please note that `sed -i` does not change the original file. It creates a new file and overwrites the original file, breaking hard links along the way. [reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=xBANKuFJWtUC&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=sed+-i+does+not+change+the+original+file&source=bl&ots=_qcIKN5EHZ&sig=mZhVOl0-aBZ03TfrdSA28PsxINE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CmvEUrHQEaGj0QWllIC4CA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=sed%20-i%20does%20not%20change%20the%20original%20file&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are on UNIX. When you do this:

```
cmd file > file
```

where "cmd" is any UNIX command, you run the risk of "file" being overwritten by "> file" BEFORE it's read by "cmd file" so never do that.

Some tools like "sed" have options that allow "in-place" editing so the result of running that command on the input file is written back to that file. Most of them use temp files behind the scenes.

The safe, portable way to get the results of command written back to file is just to redirect the output to a tmp file and then move the temp file onto the original:

```
cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Safe, simple, and works for any command.

For your particular case of just looking for lines in a file that don't contain a particular word, the command you probably want is "grep" and you'd use it as:

```
grep -v acetate filename.txt > tmp && mv tmp filename.txt
```

For anything more complicated you'll probably want awk.

Answer (score 2):

sputnick has given a relatively complete answer, I add a grep way:

```
grep -v 'acetate' file > newfile
```

Comment: Thanks kent, if is not ask to much, what about if I want to include more words?

Comment: e.g. you want to do with words foo, bar, baz. questions is you want to delete line with those three words in AND relation or OR? if OR, grep can do it simply. but AND, you need `grep | grep | grep -v` which is not so nice. better go with awk

Answer (score 1):

Your command is ok, but you can't use the same file as input and output. You should use a pivot file and then move it:

```
awk 'match($0,"acetate") == 0 {print $0}' filename.txt > filename.tmp<br>
mv -f filename.tmp filename.txt
```