# Using sed to replace one line (that might change) with another

Tags: replace, sed, grep

I want to run a script that changes a line in the HTML code, indicating when the page was last updated. So for instance, I have the line

`<d>This page was last updated on 29.04.2013 at 00:34 UTC</d>`

and I am updating it now, so I want to replace that line with

`<d>This page was last updated on 15.05.2013 at 15:50 UTC</d>`

This is the only line in my source code that has the `<d>` tag, so hopefully that helps. I already have some code that generates the new string with the current date and time, but I can't figure out a way to replace the old one (which changes, so I don't know *exactly* what it is).

I've tried putting in a comment `<!--date-->` in the previous line, deleting the whole line that has `<d>` (with `grep`), and then putting in a new line after the comment that is the new string, but that fails. For example, if I want to just insert the string `text` after the comment, and use

`sed -i 's/<!--date-->/<!--date-->text/' file.html`

I get `invalid command code j`. I think it might be because there are some special characters like `<`,`!`, and `>` in the strings, but if I want to put in the date string above, I will have even more, like `:` and `/`. Thanks for any ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: Believe it or not, I think the problem is that you are using `csh` or some other shell that is trying to do a history expansion on the `!` inside single quotes.  Try using a different shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the text only on lines that contain `<d>`:

```
sed -i.bak "/<d>/s/on .* at [^<]*/on newdate at newtime/" file.html
```

I've tested this with the BSD sed that ships with MacOS X 10.8.3

Comment: Perfect. Creates a `.bak` file too, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: I've been bitten a couple of times by not having that bak file, so I put it in without thinking. You can, of course, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your <!--date--> hack.  You can use regular expressions and another delimiter besides "/" in your sed command:

```
sed -i.bak 's@<d>This page was last updated on.*</d>@<d>This page was last updated on 12.05.2013 at 00:38 UTC</d>@' whatever.html
```

Or, if you have your update in a variable called $replacement:

```
sed -i.bak "s@<d>This page was last updated on.*</d>@$replacement@" whatever.html
```

Comment: Nope, in both cases, using `bash` or `sh`, I get the same error. I should mention I'm running Mac OS 10.7.5

Comment: Hmm ... works in bash, csh, and zsh on my Linux box ... sorry then, I don't know!

Comment: OK, see [this](https://github.com/bergie/create/pull/119) ... you need a "backup" extension on your -i ... -i.bak or whatever.

Comment: Great, now it works! But there should be no space between `-i` and `.bak`, otherwise it fails.

Comment: That's funny ... I originally had it without the space, but I saw [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux) which had a space.

Answer (score 0):

When using the command line, try escaping special characters like this:
`!` ===> `\!`

Comment: No dice. Same error, using it only for `!`, or for `!`,`<`, and `>`.