# Getting an error with sed expression

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, aix

I am using this command in a shell script

```
lnum=5
str="Hello foo"
filename="/path/fiename"   

 sed -i "$lnum i $str" $filename
```

Getting the following error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: : doesn't want any addresses
```

I had used this command before for other script it worked fine, the only change i made this time is file-name has a path to the file, but I tried it with just giving file-name and not the path by getting into the path and executing the script but still it doesn't work

I am unable  to resolve it can anybody help

Comment: *Hint*: Where did the separator go?

Comment: I've tried in a script and works fine to me. Post some more info, which `shell` are you using? Which version of `sed`?

Comment: AIX `sed` (if that is the one you're using) does not seem to support the `-i` switch; also insertion (`i`) command needs to be followed with a `\\` (see [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds5%2Fsed.htm))

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OSX , BSD (and AIX) versions of `sed`, the backup extension for the `-i` in place editing flag is *not optional*.

GNU `sed` differs on this I believe, so the script may work on Linux.

This is a bit of a pain for portability - but it gets worse with "in-place" editing when BSD derived `sed` is used. This version of `sed` is arguably more "standard" in some ways (as in: "lowest common denominator across POSIX systems") but this behaviour seems like a bug:

```
sed: 1: "5 i hello foo": command i expects \ followed by text
```

Here is how I made your script work on several BSD flavors:

```
lnum="5"
str="Hello foo"                                                                 
filename="sed-mess.txt"

sed -i "" "$lnum i\^M 
$str" $filename
```

I had to enter a literal line end character with `Ctrl-v [Return]` to get the `i` command to work since `\` is required and has to have *nothing* following it.    Not sure how GNU `sed` would handle this.

Can you  use `perl` ? ;-)

Comment: See [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux) for more discussion. POSIX, save us!

Answer (score 0):

The old farts use ed for this type of problem:

cat /tmp/sample

```
#!/bin/ksh

lnum=5
str="Hello bar"
filename="/tmp/foo"

ed - $filename <<EOF
$lnum
i
$str
.
w
q
EOF
```

cat /tmp/foo

```
line
line
line
line
line
line
line
line
line
```

wc /tmp/foo

```
   9       9      45 /tmp/foo
```

/tmp/sample

```
line
```

wc /tmp/foo

```
  10      11      55 /tmp/foo
```

cat /tmp/foo

```
line
line
line
line
Hello bar
line
line
line
line
line
```

`i` is "insert" before while `a` is "append" after.  I don't know what the sed i command does exactly but I would expect it would be the same as `i`

Hope this helps

Comment: Curious why someone thought this answer wasn't useful.  It demonstrates how do use ed rather than sed.  sed has various limitations that ed doesn't have.