# Why doesn't sed recognize the \ character?

Tags: unix, sed

I have a lot of \ in a file that I would like to remove using sed. Here is my command:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\\\//g' myFile
```

And I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "i.bak": command i expects \ followed by text.
```

Shouldn't it work. I tried:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\\//g' myFile
```

But I get the same error.

Thank you.

Comment: This is because osx does not admit `-i.bak`. You need to indicate `-i 'bak'`. There are many questions like this, cannot find the proper one now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an error with sed expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470697/getting-an-error-with-sed-expression)

Comment: It could be a shell issue, did you try sed -i'.bak' ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `sed` on OS X and when you want to change file in-place using `-i` flag, then you need to specify the extension for saving backups of that file.

Check out `man sed` section about `-i` flag:

```
 -i extension
         Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is
         given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-
         place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is
         exhausted, etc.
```

So, the correct command would be:

```
sed -i "bak" "s/\\\//g" myFile
```

And if you do not want to make backup file, you could just write like this:

```
sed -i "" "s/\\\//g" myFile
```

If you want to make your script platform independent you can check the `$OSTYPE` environment variable for that:

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
  sed -i "" "s/\\\//g" myFile
else
  sed -i "s/\\\//g" myFile
fi
```