# sed throws 'bad flag in substitute command'

Tags: macos, command-line, sed

I want to run a simple command of replacing absolute paths to relative ones inside a CSS file like this:

```
sed -i 's/\/fonts/../fonts/' /Users/sergeybasharov/WebstormProjects/snap/compiled/Content/stylesheets/style.css
```

It throws this

```
sed: 1: "/Users/sergeybasharov/W ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'b'
```

What can be wrong in this simple script?

Comment: There's no `b` anywhere in your command, it must not be what you actually typed. Please paste the actual script.

Comment: Yes, really, just used a shorter equivalent :). I have updated to the full variant.

Comment: There's some issue with your quoting that's causing the filename to be included in the subsitute command, but I don't see it in what you've quoted. You're missing a backslash, though.

Comment: The error you're reporting would happen if you had `-e` before the filename or you were missing the `s/\fonts` command at the beginning. It's treating the filename as a sed instruction.

Comment: I have read `man` for sed. It's written there that after -i I should use extension that is used to make a backup file. If empty string is provided, then no backup will be created. So I have put it like `-i ''` and it worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed command failing on Mac, but works on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In your command `s/\/fonts/../fonts/` is being taken as the parameter to the `-i` option (the suffix to use for the backup file), and the filename argument is being treated as the editing commands.

You need to specify to disable the backup file creation:

```
sed -i '' ...
```

In your example:

```
sed -i '' 's/\/fonts/../fonts/' /Users/sergeybasharov/WebstormProjects/snap/compiled/Content/stylesheets/style.css
```

Computers are dumb, they don't figure things out by context, so they can't tell that something beginning with `s/` is *obviously* an editing command, not a suffix.

Comment: +1, interesting, in Windows I don't have this problem, I must always use double quotes.

Comment: @Endoro  The type of quotes are irrelevant in this case, the important thing is that you have to have an explicit argument there.

Comment: Maybe in `OSX` sed, in `GNU` sed `-i` works without an argument. Good to know :)

Comment: @purpletech See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux

Comment: You're a star Barmar! On a Mac this is what you need.  Thanks-

Answer (score 43):

`sed -i 's/\/fonts/../fonts/'` is not a valid sed command, try `sed -i 's#/fonts#../fonts#'`

Comment: Totally forgot you can use different delimiters in sed. This solved my issue because my substitution contained slashes. Brilliant!

Comment: Thank you! I also had slashes in my substitution.

Answer (score 24):

I was having a similar issue. You can install the GNU version of sed in your Mac, called gsed, and use it using the standard Linux syntax.

For that, install gsed using ports (if you don't have it, get it at http://www.macports.org/) by running sudo port install gsed. Then, you can run:

```bash
gsed -i 's/old_pattern/new_pattern/g' *
```

Comment: Equivalent if using homebrew is brew install gnu-sed

Comment: Worked like a charm with `gsed`.. I did install gsed on mac using `brew install gsed`

Answer (score 11):

in sed you can use any character to split, in my case I had / in one of the strings hence the error so I had to replace / with | in the sed split; hope this helps others

```
STRING1="something/somethingelse"
STRING2="clean"

sed -i '' "s|${STRING1}|${STRING2}|g" FILE
```