# Deleting a line from a file in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to delete a line from a file and update the file to reflect that. I'm running a bash command inside a python program. The line delete works on the terminal, but the file isn't updated.

```
subprocess.call("sed -e $d {}".format(self._path).split())
```

How can I update the file to not have this line anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should add the `-i` flag to sed command to edit the file in-place.

On BSD's sed:

```
subprocess.call("sed -i '' -e $d {}".format(self._path).split())
```

On GNU's sed:

```
subprocess.call("sed -i -e $d {}".format(self._path).split())
```

Comment: If you are on OSX you should use `-i ''` (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17535174/520275)