# Replace a string by a newline

Tags: bash

I have this text file. I want to replace the occurence of a string by newline. Lets say I have this string test. I want to replace every occurence of this string by a newline. How can I do it in the shell

Answer (score 1):

If you use `sed`:

```
sed 's/abc/\n/' inupt.txt > output.txt
```

Suppose `input.txt` contains:

```
abc helo
a b c
```

You will end up with:

```
[newline]
  helo
a b c
```

Tested on `Ubuntu 13.10` with `sed 4.2`, `bash 4.2`.

Comment: It replaces abc by n not newline

Comment: @user34790 Are we using the same `bash` or the same `sed`? Or did you forget the backslash? or single quote?  It works fine on my machine :)

Comment: @user34790 Might this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux) be of some help? This works on Ubuntu. I don't know about Mac.  If it dosen't work, maybe just use some editor on Mac, do find and replace :)

Comment: If you are using `bash`, use `sed $'/abc/\n/' input.txt > output.txt` to guarantee that `sed` gets a newline, whether or not `sed` itself understands `\n` to be a newline.

Comment: @user34790 Another reason to forget about Mac if I want Linux.  Thanks for your response on Mac :P

Comment: @chepner Are you sure that syntax works?

Comment: Oops. `sed` still needs the newline itself escaped, so it should be `sed $'/abc/\\\n/'`, so that `sed` sees `\` + `<newline>` as the replacement text.

Comment: @chepner Sorry, but it's still not working on my machine.