# "invalid command code ." while trying to use grep and sed to replace string in multiple files

Tags: regex, macos, unix, sed, grep

Unix (and SO) newbie here trying to flex my nascent command line chops.

I'm trying to use grep and sed to scan a bunch of files in my current directory and replace all occurrences of the string "192.168.1.1" with the string "192.168.1.0" while leaving the .git folder alone.

I tried the following:

```
grep -lr --exclude-dir=".git" "192.168.1.1" . | xargs sed -i 's/192.168.1.1/192.168.1.0/g'
```

and I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "./contact.html": invalid command code .
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me figure out what's wrong with my command.

I would also be interested in learning about a more efficient way to do this task, particularly if the command is less verbose and thus easier to remember and as long as it does not involve writing a script in perl/bash/etc, but I'm currently trying to drill down sed and grep and I would still be interested in learning about why this command isn't working even if a working alternative was provided.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4247068/873282

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change your sed command to:

```
 xargs sed -i.bak 's/192\.168\.1\.1/192\.168\.1\.0/g'
```

sed on OSX needs a valid file extension with `-i` option.

Comment: This worked, but with the annoying side effect of producing .bak files which then had to be removed. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: `.bak` is not annoying but a very secure feature where you can recover original file in case something goes wrong. But if you really don't want it then use: **`xargs sed -i '' 's/192.168.1.1/192.168.1.0/g'`**

Comment: .bak is not very useful when I'm already using version control software like git for recovery. The second one does exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: Just add ```find . -type f -name '*.bak' -delete```