# Undefined step reference InteliJ + Cucumber for Java + Maven project

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I am having problems with defining the step and mapping it to the scenario. 
I have installed maven, set up the dependencies for java, and installed cucumber for java plugin altogether with external libraries in IntelliJ.

There are 3 errors occurred in this step:
"Class Steps is never used"
"Constructor Steps is never used" 
"Lambda expressions are not supported at language level"

What is the exact problem here?

```
import cucumber.api.PendingException;

public class Steps {
    public Steps() {
        Given("^I navigate to the login page$", () -> {
            // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
            throw new PendingException();
        });
    }
}
```

This is the example of the Step which is created

Comment: The first two things are not errors, but warnings, and these warnings can be safely ignored in the context of a Cucumber test.

Comment: Also, what language level is your project on?

Answer (score 0):

First two messages are just warnings - because you created `Steps` class, but didn't use it (and, of course, didn't use constructor of `Steps` class).

For the last one you need to change language level at least to `8.0 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.` to allow *lambda expressions* usage (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22704620/10721592) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27726077/10721592) answers).