# bash - replacing string with sed

Tags: bash, csv, sed

For some mysterious reason, some elements in my CSV data appear as `s/stWgvN52??f2&amp; ?&quot;` instead of `stWgvN522tw0JtZZnyXj`, which messes up the file because I have `;` set as the CSV delimiter.

I attempted to replace the defective string using `sed` as follows:

```
$ sed -i 's/stWgvN52??f2&amp; ?&quot;/stWgvN522tw0JtZZnyXj/g' file.csv
```

but I get the following error:
    sed: 1: "access_logs_2014-04.csv": command a expects \ followed by text

What is the reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed command failing on Mac, but works on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the `-i` option, you have to specify the extension of the backup file that gets made. Some versions of `sed` expect the extension directly appended to the `-i` option, so what you wrote would work. But other versions (like the version on OS X) require it to be a separate option, so you have to write:

```
sed -i '' 's/stWgvN52??f2&amp; ?&quot;/stWgvN522tw0JtZZnyXj/g' file.csv
```

to specify that you don't want a backup file.

Comment: If you escape `?` in a normal regexp it behaves as a extended regexp and becomes a metacharacter that accepts zero or one of the preceeding character (GNU sed). So unless you are using the extended regexp switch `-r` (perhaps -E in other seds) you do not need to escape it.

Comment: It's so hard to remember the details of every regexp variation. I thought `?` was a basic RE, not extended RE.