# sed replacement command not working on Mac

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace some text in a CMakelists.txt file with the value of a bash variable using sed, but I'm getting an error:

```
sed: 1: "'s/iPhone": invalid command code ?
```

sed command:

```
sed -i "" 's/iPhone Developer/'$PROVPROF'/g' CMakelists.txt
```

PROVPROF will always have something with this format:

```
iPhone Developer: Firstname Lastname (Numbers/Letters)
```

Comment: Might be the slash in `(Numbers/Letters)` try using a different delimiter in `sed`. For example: `sed -i "" 's@iPhone Developer@'$PROVPROF'@g' CMakelists.txt`

Comment: Sorry, Numbers/Letters is just a place holder for a combination of random numbers and letters.  So for example: (8DF76DS89F)

Comment: And changing the delimiter did nothing.

Comment: Perhaps try double quoting the `s` command. `sed -i "" "s/iPhone Developer/$PROVPROF/g" CMakelists.txt`

Comment: @Otto45 Are you running this on a script?

Comment: Nevermind I think I now have an idea where you're running it. I hope you update your post with all the details.

Comment: I'm running this command from a bash script, hence the bash variable $PROVPROF

Comment: And using double quotes does nothing either.

Comment: @Otto45 Mind showing your whole script?

Comment: The space in the value of `PROVPROF` is causing the string holding the `sed` command to be split into multiple arguments, which `sed` cannot reassemble.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  How would I go about passing in the value of PROVPROF so that sed recognizes it as one string?

Comment: @Otto45 Please show your whole script so we can help you.

Comment: I got it to work.  I was able to solve it by putting two sets of quotes around my variable like so: `sed -i "" "s|iPhone Developer|""$PROVPROF""|g" CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 14):

The reason this doesn't work is because sed on linux is different that sed on mac. In order for your commands to work as intended, I recommend installing gnu-sed through homebrew.

You can do this via: `brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names`

NOTE: `--with-default-names` flag will attempt to symlink gnu-sed with your sed, should be what you want but if not, I warned you!

then run `hash -r` on bash, or `rehash` on zsh.

If it does not work after that, you must manually symlink gnu-sed with sed via:

`ln -s /usr/local/bin/gsed $(which sed)`

Comment: brew cannot handle (anymore) --with-default-names you can just run brew install gnu-sed

Comment: @UgurKazdal you can run `brew info gnu-sed` and it will tell you what to add to your PATH variable. You should add that to your .bashrc or .zshrc file in your home directory.

Comment: @josue.0 thank you you are right

Answer (score 6):

If you have characters in your variable which are the same as the delimiter you used to `s`, try using another delimiter instead:

```
sed -i '' "s|iPhone Developer|$PROVPROF|g" CMakelists.txt
```

Something more rare:

```
sed -i '' $'s\xFFiPhone Developer\xFF'"$PROVPROF"$'\xFFg' CMakelists.txt
```

#### Update:

Also, don't try to store your arguments on a variable. Word splitting would not always work the way you do. This is wrong:

```
command="sed -i '' 's|iPhone Developer|$PROVPROF|g' CMakelists.txt"
$command
```

Error message like `` sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `'' `` would appear. On other `sed`s the message may be different.

But you can use an array:

```
command=(sed -i '' "s|iPhone Developer|$PROVPROF|g" CMakelists.txt)
"${command[@]}"
```

It's still not commendable though. If you can run it directly, run it directly.

Comment: I think with OSX you might need the empty quotes on `-i`. [Check the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux?lq=1). And check the comments to the question, the `/` isn't actually in the variable

Comment: I see. I removed the comment then.

Answer (score 4):

With `mytxt.txt` containing:

```
hi soldiers
```

Working cmd:

```
sed -i '' "s/hi/hello/" mytxt.txt
```

It's worked for me 100% sure for mac users

follow this link
https://singhkays.com/blog/sed-error-i-expects-followed-by-text/

Output:

```
hello soldiers
```

Comment: I prefer this simple answer, which I tested with my MacBook and works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

With `file.txt` containing:

```
Angelina used to like iPhone Developers.
Now she's more of an Android Developer fan-girl.
```

and Bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
export MONKEY_1="Billy Bob";
export MONKEY_2="Brad Pitt";

sed -e "s/iPhone Developer/$MONKEY_1/g" -e "s/Android Developer/$MONKEY_2/g" file.txt
```

running it yields:

```
Angelina used to like Billy Bobs.
Now she's more of an Brad Pitt fan-girl.
```