# OSX - Change files include directive from angle brackets to double quote

Tags: sed

i have about 1000 file with angle brackets include directive. I'd like to change this directive with any kind of script like the example below:

```
#include <file.h>
```

to:

```
#include "file.h"
```

or

```
#include <dir/file.h>
```

to

```
#inlcude "dir/file.h"
```

Thanks in advance.

---- EDITING -----
i have tried this script:

```
for myfile in $(find ./include); do

        sed -i '/^#include/s/<\([^>]*\)>/"\1"/' "${myfile}" > /dev/null
done
```

but the result is: 
sed: 1: "./include/DIR/FILE.h": invalid command code .

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried? Any leads that we can help you with? Find/replace with regular expressions might be one solution.

Comment: Should be doable with a bit of `find ... -exec stuff` or `find ... | xargs stuff` where `stuff` is some `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: You say it's not working, but you create the `hfile` variable and try to use the `myfile` variable. So **sed** sees no input file and waits for something on stdin... :(

Comment: sed: 1: "./include/AFILE.h": invalid command code .

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/^#[[:blank:]]*include/s/<\([^>]*\)>/"\1"/' your_input
```

This only modifies lines that start with `#include` and in those lines, it replaces `< ... >`
 by `" ... "`, using a backreference (`\1`) to designate the content inside the brackets.

And if you want to do that on a number of files, just include that in a Bash loop, with the `-i` option of GNU **sed** to do the transformation directly into the file:

```
for myfile in ...
do
  sed -i'' '/^#[[:blank:]]*include/s/<\([^>]*\)>/"\1"/' "${myfile}"
done
```

Comment: the bash script say: -i may not be used with stdin

Comment: Note the OP is on OSX, and `sed -i` does not work there. Hence, it is best to just use a normal `sed '...' file > new_file && mv new_file file`. Or use `sed -i '' '...' file`, or even `sed -i.bak '...' file`.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui, I have edited consequently. Personally, I almost never use this `-i` option anyway, it's always better practice to backup when you do large batch alterations... And only delete after you have checked everything is ok (in this case, after compiling the project).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files are under the directory `directory-name`:

```
grep -rl '#include <.*>' directory-name/ | xargs sed -i 's/#include <\(.*\)>/#include "\1"/g'
```

Comment: The ANSI norm accepts an arbitrary number of spaces or tabulations after `include`...

Comment: @Pasquale on a linux or is it osx?

Comment: OSX. sorry for the lack of clarification

Comment: @Pasquale see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux#4247319 OSX requires backups to be given as param. you could give empty quotes as in `sed -i '' ...`