# sed - delete all lines that contain one pattern but not another

Tags: bash, sed

I want to delete all lines in a file that contain one pattern, but not another.

For example, if I have this file:

```
hello people foo
hello world bar
hello something
blah blah blah
```

I want to delete all lines that contain `hello`, but not `world`, so that my file looks like this:

```
hello world bar
blah blah blah
```

I tried the following:

```
sed -n '/hello/p' file | sed -i '/world/!d'
```

But I get the error message `-i may not be used with stdin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an awk alternative:

```
awk '!/hello/ ||/world/' file
```

Comment: unfortunately the sed answers didn't work for me, so I implemented this one

Comment: This does not modify the file but just return the output. How do you save it to file ?

Comment: @BigDong `awk '...' file > hello.tmp && mv hello.tmp file`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I did `| tee file` for this. Do you know how to replace `hello` with `$HOSTNAME` ?

Answer (score 6):

This should work

```
sed  -i '/hello/{/world/!d}' file
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't, I have a file called git, and I run the sed command as so: sed -i '/hello/{/world/!d}' git  ... and I get this error:sed: 1: "git": extra characters at the end of g command

Comment: Similar results as @Bolboa here, but error is `sed: 1: "testfile.txt": undefined label 'estfile.txt'`. Tested on OS X 10.9.5.

Answer (score 5):

A single sed invocation:

```
sed -n '/hello/ {/world/d; p}' file
```

For lines matching `/hello/`, if it also matches `/world/` delete, else print

Comment: hmmm... this is the error I get: sed: 1: "/hello/ {/world/d; p}": extra characters at the end of p command... Any reason why?

Comment: Excellent solution glenn. @Bolboa, check your syntax, worked perfectly on Linux exactly as `sed -n '/hello/ {/world/d; p}'`

Comment: this does not print the line 'blah blah blah'

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, I really like the solution too, but I guess I should've mentioned that I am using OSX, does that make a difference?

Comment: Oh should be `sed -n '/hello/ {/world/d};p'` now it works perfect... (Glenn, take a look an perhaps tweak your answer)

Comment: @Bolboa, check out the OSX sed man page: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html

Comment: this deleted line containing world. Except I have replaced word with '172.16.'

Comment: This does the exact opposite of what the question asked for. This prints *no* line (because of `-n`) except those that contain “hello” (because of `p`) and not “world” (because of `d`). A working invocation is `sed '/hello/ {/world/p; d}'`. It works as follows. For any line that contains “hello”, firstly we print it immediately (`p`) *if* it also contain “world”, then (`;`) we discard it (`d`) anyway. For any other line, we print it untouched.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i.bak '/hello/{/world/!d}
```

this answer is different since an extension is provided to -i.

I the thread below should be useful

[sed command with -i option failing on Mac, but works on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux)

Comment: This is just the same as 1_CR posted 20 minutes before you.

Comment: @Jotne Yes.. i think the -i without an extension could be the reason why the OP is getting an error using this simple solution (an assumption since I don't have OS X). Slight difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk to keep the logic simply as-stated:

```
$ awk '/hello/ && !/world/{next} 1' file
hello world bar
blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing a round a bit, I was able to procure one script implementing `sed`, which worked for me:

```
file=$1
patt=$(sed -n '/world/p' $file)
sed -n "/hello/!p;/$patt/p" $file
```