# Bash sed delete line from file not working

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to delete a line from a text file that has a matching ID number.

Student id variable: `$sid`, for example `12345678`;
`$FILE` = `student_record`

I first tried:

```
sed -i '/$sid/d' student_record.txt
```

Which gave me file not found. Next:

```
sed -i '/$sid/d' $FILE
```

And I get: `sed: 1: "student_record": unterminated substitute in regular expression`

```
sed -i '/12345678/d' $FILE
```

Same error as above

```
sed -i '/$sid/ d' student_record.txt
```

yields:

```
sed 1: "student_record.txt": bad flag in substitute command: 'x'
```

If I try without `-i`,

```
sed '/$sid/ d' $FILE
```

It just prints the whole file and doesn't delete any lines.

Advice would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is called `student_record` as you say for `$FILE`, you may be making a mistake using `student_record.txt` which would explain while you get `file not found`.

For many of the others, if you use single quotes it will not expand variables, so you'll literally be looking for the string "$sid".  If you use double quotes it will expand, so try

```
sed -i "/$sid/d" "$FILE"
```

assuming you have GNU sed.  If you're on something that does not have GNU, you may not have `-i` or it may require an argument.

Comment: Yeah I am using Mac OSX so I just had a look there was an answer stating that you "need to provide an extension for your backups", so for the sed command it would be, sed -i ' ' "/$sid/d" $FILE, and that seems to work! Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux