# How to delete lines in a ".data" file?

Tags: linux, sed

I have an enormous file, about 10 MB, and it has about 175,000 lines. I tried truncated it like this:

```
sed '500,175000d' <file-name.data>
```

I reopen the file, and all of the lines are still there!  I tested this with other files and it works. For some reason the .data extension doesn't work? How do I delete these lines?

Comment: weird that they don't mention that [here](http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/06/delete-range-of-lines-unix-linux.html)  thanks

Comment: Actually you need `sed -i.bak ....`

Comment: That's unusual under Linux (which appears in the tags). BSD sed needs an extension argument to `-i` (or at least an empty string), GNU sed doesn't, and all Linux distributions I know ship GNU sed. Of course, it doesn't hurt to have a backup in case things go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either redirect the output to a new file like

```
sed '500,175000d' file-name.data >newFile
```

or use the edit in place option which rewrites the input file

```
sed -i '500,175000d' file-name.data
```

as pointed out by  Wintermute

***Edit:***

A faster sed would be just

```
sed -i '500q' file-name.data # prints 1-500 and quits after line 500
```

Comment: The "faster" sed that you mention:  If I do `sed -i '500q' file-name` then it gives me an error:  `file-name extra characters at the end of command`.  And, if I do `sed -i.bak '500q' file-name`, then it doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't change the file at all.  My OS is Darwin Kernel version 14.3.0.

Comment: There are two implementations of sed(or more), look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux). Also there should be a space between -i and .bak