# Why is my rails db:migrate not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I typed in `rails db:migrate` and received the following error. I googled and someone said something like changing the Migration version from [4.2] to [5.1] but it still has not worked.

> rails db:migrate
>   rails aborted!
>   StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:
>
> class CreateCkeditorAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]

Comment: can you paste complete backtrace?

Comment: Show your migration. Also what's your rails version

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Rails 5 changed the way migrations are created. You'll have to specify the Rails release starting Rails 5 like this (assuming you're using Rails 5.1):

```
class CreateCkeditorAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
```

Alternately, you can try creating a test migration and see how your version of Rails generates a migration and then take it from there:

```
rails g model Test name:string
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasnt able to fix this issue until I found out that I was looking at the files within the ckeditor folder instead of the migration file!!

Comment: Is the value inside the brackets the version of Rails that you are running the migration in, or the version of Rails where the migration was created? That is, if I wrote a migration under 4.2 that I am applying to a Rails 5 environment, should I use 4.2 or 5.1 inside the braces?

Comment: @PhilDD It should be 4.2

Comment: Thank you, the error occurred for me after installing and configuring Paperclip/ImageMagick combo.   I added my [5.1] to the end of the first line of the related migration file like so... 

class AddAttachmentImageToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]

Answer (score 57):

[Aditya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2962667/aditya) already wrote the answer, Changing all migrations by hand is a hectic task, So I wrote a one liner script to do that

In linux (Gnu sed)

```
grep -rl "ActiveRecord::Migration$" db | xargs sed -i 's/ActiveRecord::Migration/ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]/g'
```

In Mac (BSD sed)

```
grep -rl "ActiveRecord::Migration$" db | xargs sed -i "" "s/ActiveRecord::Migration/ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]/g"
```

Note, you can replace `4.2` with the rails from which you are upgrading to 5.1

Comment: ^ This is awesome and saved me a bunch of time.

Comment: I run this command `grep -rl "ActiveRecord::Migration$" db | xargs sed -i 's/ActiveRecord::Migration/ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]/g'`  but its not working i am getting this output `sed: no input files`

Comment: @Nency Which OS ?

Comment: On macOS Mojave the BSD sed script provided doesn't work, use the Gnu sed one.

Comment: Is this really advisable? Let's say I'm updating from 4.2. Could it cause issues if some of the migrations were written prior to 4.2?

Comment: @Daniel I did this for multiple projects, this worked without any issues

Comment: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/01/migrations-are-versioned-in-rails-5.html explains why it's safe.

Comment: I get this error when I run the command on ubuntu
```sed: can't read s/ActiveRecord::Migration/ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]/g: No such file or directory
```

Comment: @chrisgeeq hi, probably too late, but you need to remove space sign between `-i` and `""` as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247319/6860421