# OS X 'RE error: invalid repetition count(s)'

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I'm trying to replace the following (in it's simplest form)

```
{filedir_9}file.jpg
```

with

```
{filedir_7}file.jpg
```

Using

```
sed -i -e 's/(\{filedir_9\})([a-z\-\_0-9]+).jpg/\{filedir_7\}$2$3/g'
```

But I'm getting : RE error: invalid repetition count(s)

Comment: Try `sed -i '' -e 's/{filedir_9}\([-a-z_0-9]\{2,\}\)\.jpg/{filedir_7}\1/g'`. Why do you want to use Group 3 placeholder if you tried to capture two subpatterns? Note that `\{` opens a limiting quantifier in a POSIX BRE pattern, you need `{` to match a literal `{`. To create a capturing group you need `\(...\)`, not `(...)` and inside the replacement, you should use `\1` to refer to Group 1 value. In POSIX patterns, escaped sequences inside bracket expressions are not supported, you should put `-` at the start/end of the pattern, escaping it does not work.

Comment: thank you, that helped get what i needed

Comment: I posted an answer with some more explanations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i '' -e 's/{filedir_9}\([-a-z_0-9]\{2,\}\)\.jpg/{filedir_7}\1/g'
```

Note that `\{` opens a limiting quantifier in a POSIX BRE pattern, you need `{` to match a literal `{`.

To create a capturing group in a BRE POSIX pattern, you need `\(...\)`, not `(...)` and inside the replacement, you should use `\1` to refer to Group 1 value.

In POSIX patterns, escaped sequences inside bracket expressions are not supported, you should put `-` at the start/end of the pattern, escaping it does not work (the `\` is treated as a literal `\` char).

Also, to match a dot, you need to escape the `.` char in the pattern, if it is unescaped, it matches any char.

Inside the replacement string, you should use `\1` rather than `$1` (Perl-like placeholders). Note you are using placeholders to Group 2 and 3, while your `(\{filedir_9\})([a-z\-\_0-9]+).jpg` pattern only attempts to capture 2 substrings, and thus there is no Group 3 (so, no point using `$3` or `\3`, it is empty).

Comment: Fantastic! One question, what is the second param, the '' ?

Comment: @wot That is a placeholder for an empty backup. If you need to create a  backup, replace `''` with `.bak`. See [sed command with -i option failing on Mac, but works on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068).