# Bash: add an empty row after each line of each file in a directory

Tags: bash, unix

I have a directory with a series of text files and want to add a blank row after each line.

If I just wanted to alter one file, I could do this.

```
sed -i $' \n ' 00000BD7_ar.txt
```

However, how can I alter all files in the directory. Kinda like the following.

```
for file in *; do sed -i $' \n ' ${file}
```

Answer (score 0):

sed can process multiple files.

```
sed -i $' \n ' *
```

Comment: @ATMA Are you on a Mac?

Comment: @ATMA If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux