# How to use sed inside AppleScript to find/replace all instances in an html file?

Tags: macos, sed, applescript

My goal was to replace (in place) any instance of

```
src="[random text i want to remove]http
```

with

```
src="http
```

Inside of an html file. The catch: I need to use AppleScript to do this. The code is as follows:

```
set myfile to "pathto/test.html"

do shell script "sed -i 's/src=\"*.+http/src=\"http/g' " & quoted form of myfile
```

This gives the error:

```
sed: 1: "pathto/test.html": command c expects \ followed by text
```

I'm not sure what this error means...hope someone can help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed command with -i option failing on Mac, but works on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-with-i-option-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux)

Comment: I just want to edit the file in place. I don't want to have to create a backup. How should I modify this to make it work?

Comment: You do not need to create any backup, add `''` after `-i`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14813278/3832970

Comment: It still won't work.

sed -i'' 's/src=\"*.+http/src=\"http/g' pathto/test.html

Still fails.

Comment: Have you read that thread? There are at least 3 options how to do that.

Comment: I need to use AppleScript because it is part of a workflow.

Yes, I read the thread. The reason it wasn't working was because you can't use a regex with a + symbol unless you use -E, which was not part of that thread.

It also doesn't work on OSX unless you specify a backup. Edit in place does not work on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
sed -i '' -E 's/src=\"*.+http/src=\"http/g' myfile.html
```

There has to be a space after the -i.