# unable to use sed command in macos?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I want to write a line mac .bash_profile file while executing a shell script.I have tried below way but it gives error as

```
 sed -i 'export PATH='$PWD:'$PATH' $HOME/.bash_profile
```

**error**

```
sed: 1: "/Users/dhiraj/.bash_pro ...": extra characters at the end of d command
```

Kindly let me know how do i resolve it ?

Comment: You are using the `'i'` wrong (currently you are giving the `"edit in-place"` option, not the `/i` (insert before) command.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-with-i-option-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to append a line to your .bash_profile, what about

```
echo "PATH=\"$PWD:$PATH\"" >> $HOME/.bash_profile
```

?

And, if you want to be sure to insert only once:

```
grep -q -x -F 'PATH=\"$PWD:$PATH\"' $HOME/.bash_profile || echo "PATH=\"$PWD:$PATH\"" >> $HOME/.bash_profile
```

Comment: But i don't want append this line again and again if execute the script

Comment: Even with the `sed ` command you show in your question you do not avoid that problem... See my updated answer to address that requirement.