# header for a csv file from unix shell script

Tags: unix

Have to make a header for a csv file from unix shell script. It should be like below.

"Name","Place","Pincode","officename"

Tried like below. But it is not working

s_header= `echo "Name","Place","Pincode","officename"`

echo s_header>>filename.csv

Thanks you

Answer (score 7):

You can use tool like **sed**.
1i means insert at first line.

```
 sed -i -e '1i"Name","Place","Pincode","officename"' filename.csv
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work on Macs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-with-i-option-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your csv file contents are in details.csv file. You create header.csv file by printing headers into it.You also can probably try below.

```
echo "Name","Place","Pincode","officename" > header.csv && cat details.csv >> header.csv && mv header.csv details.csv
```

**Steps:**

1)Print the headers into file name **header.csv**

2)Append the contents of the csv file contents(**details.csv**) into **header.csv**

3)Rename the **header.csv** file back to your original file **details.csv**