# sed not working as expected when trying to replace "user='mysql'" with "user=`whoami`"

Tags: sed

The following command fails.

```sh
sed 's/user=\'mysql\'/user=`whoami`/g' input_file
```

An example `input_file` contains the following line

```
user='mysql'
```

The corresponding expected output is

```
user=`whoami`
```

(Yes, I literally want `whoami` between backticks, I don't want it to expand my userid.)

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: [`sed` command with `i` option failing on Mac but works on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-with-i-option-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux)

Comment: You can't insert a sinqle quote in a single quoted string, and single quotes prevent all expansions including command substitutions (the `\`whoami\`` part). Use double quotes around the sed command.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @BenjaminW.. I am not trying to substitute `whoami` but rather replace "user='mysql'" with "user=`whoami`". Isn’t it possible to escape single quotes using backslashes?

Comment: Can you show input and expected output? You want to insert a literal `\`whoami\``, if I understand correctly. As for single quotes within single quotes: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/3266847).

Comment: @BenjaminW.. Please see edit. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you need:

- Using double quotes to enclose the `sed` command,
- so that you are free to use single quotes in it;
- escape backticks to avoid the expansion.

```
sed "s/user='mysql'/user=\`whoami\`/g" yourfile
```

I've intentionally omitted the `-i` option for the simple reason that it is not part of the issue.

To clarify the relation between single quotes and escaping, compare the following two commands

- `echo 'I didn\'t know'`
- `echo 'I didn'\''t know'`

The former will wait for further input as there's an open `'`, whereas the latter will work fine, as you are concatenating a single quoted string (`'I didn'`), an escaped single quote (`\'`), and another single quoted string (`'t know'`).

Comment: So it’s not possible to escape single quotes using a backslashes?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I guess I am mislead by things like `echo "Here’s a \" which has been escaped"`.

Comment: Yes, double quotes and single quotes are very different. Btw, I've rejected your edit for the simple reason that the not the question, nor the answer, have anything specific to MacOS. I would rather suggest that you remove that detail from your own question, as it could just mislead the reader to think that something about this question is special in MacOS.

Comment: @sunknudsen The handling of quotes is done by the shell; if you use Bash, the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) says "A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.", and the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02) says "A single-quote cannot occur within single-quotes."