# How do I add a pattern to an existing pattern with sed

Tags: bash, macos, sed, substitution

I'm trying to add 'pp. ' to the following paginations but it doesn't work:

```
grep -n -o -E --color "\b(pp.\s)?\d{1,3}–\d{2,3}\b" references.txt 
3:pp. 610–623
5:102–114
8:58–70
10:245–258
12:99–120
13:70–86
16:172–195
18:389–399
25:1–13
27:104–117
29:503–516
38:501–507
40:1–14
42:450–470
46:759–785
49:1–14
53:50–62
56:1–17
59:1–17
```

the first pagination (pp. 610–623) is already written as is in the text, this is how the others should be written.

here is the command used:
`sed -E "s/(\b(pp.\s)?\d{1,3}–\d{2,3}\b)/(pp. )\1/g" references.txt`

sample of references.txt:

> References
> Bender, E., Gebru, T., McMillan-Major, A., & Shmitchel, S. (2021). On the dangers of stochastic parrots: Can language models be too big?. In Proceedings of the 2021
> ACM conference on fairness, accountability, and transparency (pp. 610–623).
> Casal, J. E., & Yoon, J (2023). Frame-based formulaic features in L2 writing pedagogy: Variants, functions, and student perceptions in academic writing. English for
> Specific Purposes, 71, 102–114. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.esp.2023.03.004
> De Costa, P., Lee, J., Rawal, H., & Li, W. (2021). Ethics in applied linguistics. In J. McKinley, & H. Rose (Eds.), The Routledge handbook of research methods in applied
> linguistics. Routledge.
> De Costa, P. I., Sterling, S., Lee, J., Li, W., & Rawal, H. (2021). Research tasks on ethics in applied linguistics. Language Teaching, 54(1), 58–70. https://doi.org/
> 10.1017/S0261444820000257
> Gass, S., Loewen, S., & Plonsky, L. (2021). Coming of age: The past, present, and future of quantitative SLA research. Language Teaching, 54(2), 245–258. https://doi.
> org/10.1017/S0261444819000430
> Hagendorff, T. (2020). The ethics of AI: An evaluation of guidelines. Minds and Machines, 30, 99–120. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11023-020-09517-8
> Halleck, G. B., & Connor, U. M. (2006). Rhetorical moves in TESOL conference proposals. Journal of English for Academic Purposes, 5, 70–86. https://doi.org/10.1016/
> j.jeap.2005.08.001

No modification is made to the text and I don't have any errors either.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: please update the question with a small sample (eg, 5 lines) from `references.txt` along with the expected output

Comment: "accepting" an answer (the green checkmark) is enough, no need to add "resolved" to your title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. This should work:

`sed -E "s/:(pp\. )?(.*)/:pp. \2/g" references.txt`

If you want to change the file in place, you should add the `-i` flag too:

`sed -i -E "s/:(pp\. )?(.*)/:pp. \2/g" references.txt`

Also, the first optional capture group `(pp\. )?` is present only because you said that the first line already had pagination, so I thought other lines might have it too. If you manually added that and no line has pagination, you can as well remove it:

`sed -E "s/:(.*)/:pp. \1/g" references.txt`

Comment: I've try the first one, it doesn't change anything and with the second one, I've an error 
`sed: 1: "s/:(pp\. )?(.*)/:pp. \2/g": \2 not defined in the RE`

Comment: The first command doesn't change anything because `sed` doesn't automatically change the file in place. It outputs the changes to `stout`. If you want to save the changes in place you should use the `-i` option as specified in the second command.

For the error you are getting, if you are on a MacOS, then you want to read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-with-i-option-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux

The solution is to use the first command and then output to a file: `sed -E "s/:(pp\. )?(.*)/:pp. \2/g" references.txt > references_modified.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the article you sent me, I found how to solve my problem, I needed to install gnu-sed. Without this, the modifications would not be made.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/\b([0-9]{1,3}–[0-9]{2,3})\b/pp. \1/g' references.txt
```

This command will find any pagination like "102–114" and replace it with "pp. 102–114".

- `\b`: asserts position at a word boundary.
- `([0-9]{1,3}–[0-9]{2,3})`: captures a pagination pattern.
- `\1`: refers to the first capturing group.